# PHP design patterns Factories, Repositories and...?

Tags: php, laravel, oop, repository-pattern, factory-pattern

We have factories for creating complex objects. (For makin' stuff)

We have repositories for find them. (For findin' stuff)

What do we have for updating them? (For changin' stuff up)

---

Seems like a missing piece in the puzzle? I don't think it belongs in repositories, as that breaks single responsibility...

Comment: Isn't "updating" an operation that's performed on an object itself?  Or do you mean "updating" as in "persisting an existing object's changed state back to the data store"?

Comment: You'd update the object and then pass the updated object back to the repository; it doesn't matter whether your repo is holding the objects in memory or the database you're still going to do something like `$repo->save($object)`

Comment: We have repositories to persist the objects (complex or not). Persistence include finding but also storing (new or updated) objects (to have something to find later).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating an Entity (and so, the database) belongs to the Repository. The Repository itself is an Layer between the Database itself and the program.

Every Database Operation therefore belongs to the Repository. Also, a Repository mustn't communicate with a database, it also could have an XML, CSV or API as data source. But that doesn't matter, because you're communicating with the Repository. The Repository deals with all that's coming afterwards.

You could just change the Repository with another one and your program would work without any problems, because the repositories all implement the same interface. You don't like that MySQL Database anymore, that old fashioned CSV is much better? Just replace the used Repository and you're done.

Finding an entry with an repository isn't more than a `SELECT` statement, so why won't you `UPDATE` or `DELETE` with it?

Further reading on the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx)

Found a great explanation and example on [web.archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20150404154203/https://www.remondo.net/repository-pattern-example-csharp/)

Comment: Disagree. If you take that logic "Every Database Operation therefore belongs to the Repository." you cant scale.

Comment: Why can't you scale? Every Entity has it's own Repository, so you scale in the numbers of Entities and therefore the amount of Repositories you'll use.

Comment: Think about it. Abstracting away database interaction is not the sole reason for repositories. They are "Objects for fetching things"...Thats also Why the Factory pattern exists "Objects for creating complex things". They can both benefit from abstracting away database logic... not as you say their sole reason...

Comment: Why not have "Upgraders" that update entities with complex relations and conditions to their updating...

Comment: A factory has nothing to do with a repository. A factory is there to have a single point to create instanced of certain classes. A repository is there to have a single place for all database interaction for that certain Entity (Table). It doesn't matter if your selecting, updating or deleting on this table, the use of a repository is to provide a [SPOF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_point_of_failure) for your database interactions.

Comment: @AndrewMcLagan not always. A factory is a method that will return you a new instance of a class. The factory method CAN be creating a entry in an table, but it's not obligatory. In my opinion, if a factory method modifies the database, there's something wrong. Because the factory does more than it should be. (SPOF).

Comment: @AndrewMcLagan glad i could help. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on approach.

With DDD for example what You are saying is true. Repository should be responsible for adding, finding and removing, because it works on a collection, but there is a question why it should be able to update a single object.

What can be done? I think I will only copy what other person said, so I wil just post link to answer: [approach to removing save/update from repository](http://www.slideshare.net/Yaboomaster1/save-repository-from-save?ref=http://zawarstwaabstrakcji.pl/20151020-save-repository-from-save/)

Comment: Interesting note on `->save($object)` ... if we were to go with the bookshelf analogy though you could remove the book from the shelf, get out the TipEx to make some amendments then add it back to the bookshelf when you're done.

Comment: it's not really updating. Whay you said is removing it from collection and adding new basically ;-) what about the id for example? It overcomplicates situation.

Comment: The object knows its own id and that doesn't change - but yeah, if the repo is sitting on top of a database and automatically persisting the state of the collection it would probably all fall down.

Comment: Ok, so if object knows its own id why do we want to remove it from the shelf in the first place? I know in real world to make a change to a book, we would actually take it from the collection, make some changes and put it back in, but well, in object programming we do not have to actually remove it from anywhere, when whe want to update it. Shelf is an abstraction. Or - "there is no spoon", as Wachowski's told ya once ;-)

Comment: Heh - I'm not arguing the fact that it would be a weird thing to do in software - but that article, to my mind, made it seem like the ultimate extreme conclusion to ensure that everything is responsible only for what it should be. I'm just not entirely convinced by adding a "Unit of Work" helper object in the repo I guess. For a repo on persistent storage I'd probably do something like `$repo->dao->load()` > *do stuff* > `$repo->dao->save()` ... I'm probably missing the point somewhere ;)

Comment: There is no ultimate extreme conclusion to anything in programming. There is always "a way". And that's one of it. If you are not sure, or You have something that suits Your architecture better - go with it.